# Collecting replies to tracked hashtags using the Twitter streaming API

Tags: api, twitter, streaming

I'm cooking up a small service to allow people to post ideas on Twitter using a special hashtag, #2025ideas, and inviting their followers to comment on the ideas.

I have no problem setting up a client to track the hashtag #2025ideas and collecting them as they come in. But I'm not sure how to all have the client be notified when someone's follower replies to one of these tweets.

So say user 123456789 posts "Flying cars with autopilot #2025ideas." My client gets a notification.

Then user 987654321, who follows the origin user, replies with "And those car better have coffee makers!" I want that tweet too, but it's unreasonable to expect that user to know to use the hashtag.

The [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#filter_level) has a `replies` parameter, but it appears to only work for streaming clients that follow a specific user or site. Does anyone know how I can do this?

I could, of course, make separate occasional REST calls to the original tweet looking for replies, but this strikes me as highly inefficient and unscalable.

Comment: I would love to see this answered. I am trying to gather streaming tweets and replies to those tweets, this would be very valuable data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar use case and I would suggest altering the streaming request (whenever you receive a tweet containing your hash tag) by adding the corresponding user id that used the hash tag to the `follower` request parameter.

From the additional results you will get the following:

> - Tweets created by the user.
> - Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
> - **Replies to any Tweet created by the user.**
> - Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
> - Manual replies, created without pressing a reply button (e.g. “@twitterapi I agree”).

[See docs](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#follow) The parameter is build up as a comma-separated list.

Imo the highlighted one is the key, as you'll get replies to the tweets of the followed user. Now a bit of fiddling begins: You need to check if the tweet is a reply to one hash-tagged tweet, that you captured before. You can use the referenced `in_reply_to_status_id` to see if any of your captured tweets has the corresponding `status_id`.

As I understand this should even work, if the answering user is **not** following the original author. This is one option, there's no easy way, but I guess you knew that ;)